# Mongoid limit parameter ignored

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I tried to grab the latest N records with a unique value (first_name).

So far:

```
@users = User.all(:limit => 5, :sort => [:created_at, :desc]).distinct(:first_name)
```

almost works..But ignores the limit and sort order
Also:

```
@users = User.limit(5).desc(:created_at).distinct(:first_name)
```

Ignores both 'limit' and 'desc'

```
@users = User.limit(5)
```

Works..

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with this for a little while and this is the best I could come up with.

Good luck.

```
@users = User.desc(:created_at).reduce([]) do |arr, user|
  unless arr.length == 5 || arr.detect{ |u| u.first_name == user.first_name }
    arr << user
  end
  arr
end
```

Comment: It's going to iterate over all users every time. If you have 1000 users, no big deal but if you have 1,000,000,000, then you may want to try something else. If I can think of a better approach, I'll post a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I think it's a known issue on github: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/817

Comment: the problem is that it isn't atomic.

Comment: As @VP. noted, this is not atomic (though unlikely an issue when only grabbing 5). If you're going to do this kind of solution it really should be batched rather than attempting to load every single User object and filter server side. With any reasonable dataset (even 1000 users which you noted) this is going to be a massive drain on resources.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a pagination gem such as  amatsuda / kaminari and limiting the results using `page().per()`?

Answer (score 0):

Both `distinct` and `count` ignore the `limit` command in Mongoid. With `count` you can pass true (i.e. `User.limit(5).count(true)`) to force it to pay attention to the scope. Unfortunately there is no such trick for distinct as far as I'm aware (see docs/source [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo#distinct-instance_method)).

If you want to just grab the first 5 `first_name`'s you can do this (not distinct):

`User.desc(:created_at).limit(5).map(&:first_name)`

This will respect the limit, but still load 5 full objects from the database (then discard the rest of the object to give you full name). If you actually need to run distinct, you're better off heading toward an aggregation framework solution.

I haven't tested, but this seems to be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17568267/127311

Answer (score 0):

I played with some result I found this.

```
User.limit(2).count => 10   #but in array I found only two results
User.limit(2).to_a.count => 2
```

May be limit gives the correct result, but count query gives wrong result.